# Use Pattern with Vectors in Assumptions

Tags: equation-solving, pattern-matching, assumptions

I had a problem using `Pattern` with `Vectors` in `Assumptions`.

Here's how I use `Pattern` in `Assumptions`:

```
(* Input := *) Simplify[Element[y[i], Anything], Element[y[_], Anything]]
(* Output:= True *)
```

*Mathematica* does assume that any variable matching `y[_]` is an element of `Anything`. However, if I replace `Anything` by `Vectors[n]`, *Mathematica* no longer assumes that:

```
(* Input := *) Simplify[Element[y[i], Vectors[n]], Element[y[_], Vectors[n]]]
(* Output:= Element[y[i], Vectors[n, Complexes]] *)
```

in which I expect to get an ouput of `True`. So where is the problem?

---

Update: The problem exists only in v9, in which `Vectors` is introduced as a built-in function. (Thanks Māris Ozols for clarifying it.)

Below Michael E2 gave a solution, replacing `Element[y[_], Vectors[n]]` by `HoldPattern@Element[y[_], Vectors[n,Complexes]]`. This partially solves the problem, but it is not what I want, because it does not really assume `y[_]` is a vector. See the following code.

```
(*Input := *) $Assumptions = {HoldPattern[Element[y[_], Vectors[n, Complexes]]], 
               Element[x[1], Vectors[n]], Element[z[_], Vectors[n]]};
(*Input := *) Simplify[{Element[y[i], Vectors[n]], Element[x[1], Vectors[n]], 
               Element[z[i], Vectors[n]]}]
(*Output:= {True, True, Element[z[i], Vectors[n, Complexes]]}*)
(*Input := *) TensorRank /@ {y[i], x[1], z[i]}
(*Ouput:=  {TensorRank[y[i]], 1, TensorRank[z[i]]}*)
```

Above only `x[1]` behaves as a vector, but `y[i]` and `z[i]` not. `HoldPattern` only makes `Element[y[i], Vectors[n]]` true, but will not make `y[i]` a vector. I want `y[i]` to behave like `x[1]`.

Comment: Use `Refine[]` instead of `Simplify[]`

Comment: *Refine[expr,assum]
gives the form of expr that would be obtained if symbols in it were replaced by explicit numerical expressions satisfying the assumptions assum.*

Comment: `Simplify[Element[y[i], Vectors[n]], Element[y[_], Vectors[n]]]` gives `True` on *Mathematica* 8.0.4 for Windows. Looks like a bug in v.9.

Comment: The reason it gives `True` in _Mathematica_ 8.0.4 is that `Vectors[n]` [was introduced only in 9.0](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Vectors.html). Thus, in 8.0.4 it makes no difference if you write `Anything` or `Vectors[n]`, since neither is defined.

Comment: The problem persists even in a slightly stronger sense: `Simplify[Element[y, Vectors[n]], Element[_, Vectors[n]]]` gives `Element[y, Vectors[n, Complexes]]`.

Comment: It also persists if `Vectors` is replaced by `Matrices` or `Arrays`. But it does not appear when other domains are used, such as `Integers`. Thus, it seems that it is specific only to the new [Symbolic Tensors](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/SymbolicTensors.html) domains.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why your code does not work.  But here's a workaround:

```
Simplify[Element[y[i], Vectors[n]], hyp_ /; MatchQ[hyp, Element[y[_], Vectors[n]]]]
(* True *)
```

---

**Update**

I can add a little bit more:

`Vectors` is a defined system symbol in V9 but not in V8 or earlier.  The command

```
Simplify[Element[y[i], Foo[n]], Element[y[_], Foo[n]]]
```

returns `True` in V9, just as the command

```
Simplify[Element[y[i], Vectors[n]], Element[y[_], Vectors[n]]]
```

returns `True` in V8, as [Alexey Popkov commented](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33493/use-pattern-with-vectors-in-assumptions#comment103774_33493).  The problems seems to have to do with the pattern `Vectors[n]` being evaluated, for the pattern works when it is held:

```
Simplify[Element[y[i], Vectors[n]], HoldPattern @ Element[y[_], Vectors[n, Complexes]]]
(* True *)
```

Note: Because the pattern is held and `Vectors[n]` automatically expands to `Vectors[n, Complexes]` (when not held), I needed to substitute the correct pattern.

Comment: Could you please explain how it works? I cannot find an example of `Assumption` of such form in the Documentation and confused. What does really mean such an `Assumption`?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov  I'm not exactly sure - that is to say, I can guess.  Assumptions somehow have to be matched with (sub)expressions in order to apply them.  I had (thoughtlessly) assumed that they would be literal matches, but the OP's question showed general patterns might work.  I got a few things to be successful, and the one posted seemed simplest.  I'll try to think of a more complete explanation, if I can find one.

Comment: I don't get `True` when using `HoldPattern` in _Mathematica_ 9.0.1.

Comment: @MārisOzols  Oops, I accidentally removed `Complexes` where it was needed.  Thanks!